# Get all users in .NET Azure Active Directory groups recursively

Tags: .net, azure, active-directory

I am struggling to get all users in .NET Azure Active Directory groups recursively. I googled out but all articles are on users memberof groups for Azure Active Directory.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Anil Jain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding, to retrieve the members from group recursively, we only need to detect the type of member. If the member is group we can request the members again.

I also wrote a demo using Azure AD graph client for your reference:

```
public void testPrintMembersRecursively()
{
    var client = GraphHelper.CreateGraphClient();
    var group = (Group)client.Groups.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.First(g => g.DisplayName == "group4");
    var groupFetcher = client.Groups.GetByObjectId(group.ObjectId);

   PrintMembersRecursively(groupFetcher, 0);
}

public void PrintMembersRecursively(Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.IGroupFetcher groupFetcher, int level)
{
    var membersResoult = groupFetcher.Members.ExecuteAsync().Result;
    Print(level, membersResoult);

    while (membersResoult.MorePagesAvailable)
    {
        membersResoult=membersResoult.GetNextPageAsync().Result;
        Print(level,membersResoult);
    }
}

private void Print(int level, IPagedCollection<IDirectoryObject> membersResoult)
{
    var members = membersResoult.CurrentPage;

    foreach (var obj in members)
    {
        var user = obj as Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User;
        if (user != null)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + level * 8 + "}", user.DisplayName));
        else
        {
            var groupMember = obj as Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Group;
            if (groupMember != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0," + level * 8 + "}", groupMember.DisplayName));
                    PrintMembersRecursively(GetGroupById(groupMember.ObjectId), level + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}


public static ActiveDirectoryClient CreateGraphClient()
{
    string accessToken = "";
    string tenantId = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com"; 
    string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

    Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);    
    Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId);

    ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await Task.FromResult(accessToken));

    return activeDirectoryClient;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I cannot try this as this was taken care but since you have tried it at your end I'll mark it as accepted answer.